# Add button in footer at the end of the table view cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, footer

I am new to iphone development.I have created a UIview controller class and added a table view using interface builder. Now i want to create a  button in footer view at the end of the table view last cell. I have used UIView Controller class (not UItableview controller).How can i achieve this.

please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view with your button on it and set it for the `tableFooterView` outlet (if you are using Interface Builder) or property (if you are doing it in code) on you `UITableView`.